# Hyperledger Fabric V1.2 network setup with Zookeeper and Kafka for multiple Orderers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

I've got 4 hosts, each with an Orderer. I understanad that for multiple Orderers setup we must utilise Kafka and Zookeeper.

How would I go about deploying the network with Kafka and Zookeeper? I've tried using

```
docker-compose ... up
```

to deploy the docker services as usual but this doesn't work, eventhough I've included the `extra-hosts` key in the services mapping the service name with the IP of the machines they're on so that the services can find other.

The error I'm getting is

```
Cannot open channel to 2 at election address zookeeper2/x.x.x.x:3888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I've also checked that on all the machines the ports that the docker services uses are open and accessible.

Comment: `docker-compose up` is used only on a single machine; for swarm you can use `docker stack deploy`

Comment: I've done a network setup with a solo orderer and multiple peers on multiple machines using `docker-compose` and `extra-hosts` before, and they were able to communicate with each other. @ConstantinGalbenu, perhaps you know a way to accomplish this with the docker's `environment` key?

Comment: The simplest is to use docker swarm and it will handle the networking. Otherwise you need to export the ports from the containers to the outside.

Comment: Ok, thanks @ConstantinGalbenu. I'll need to experiment with docker swarm then. I've read that since `docker stack deploy` can do everything `docker compose` can, `docker compose` might eventually become deprecated. So I might as well experiment now.

Comment: no, docker compose is not a replacement for docker stack, they have different purposes. Docker compose is a super-useful tool for local development.